# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch, what am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am missing something here:

Price class:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :diamonds

   scope :for_diamond, -> (diamond) { where("colour = ? AND clarity = ? AND weight_min < ? AND     weight_max > ?",
                                      diamond.color_code, diamond.clarity_code, diamond.carat_weight, 
                                      diamond.carat_weight).first }

    end
  end
end
```

Diamond  Class:

```
class Diamond < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :price

  def self.import(file)
      CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      diamond = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new

      fields = row.to_hash

      diamond.price = Price.for_diamond(diamond)
      diamond.save!
    end
   end
  end
```

When I try and set the price for the diamond, using the scope Price.for_diamond, rails throws Price(#70359514373040) expected, got Price::ActiveRecord_Relation(#70359514371980)

My understanding is that this is because I the scope seems to be returning the relation and not the action record. However, I thought that adding .first to the scope would fix this.

Also, when I try this in console :

```
d = Diamond.last
d.price = Price.for_diamond(d)
d.save
```

It does seem to work.

What am I missing?

EDIT: 
 I tried changing: 
    d.price = Price.for_diamond(d)
to:
    d.price_id = Price.for_diamond(d)

No errors, but still doesn't set the price id.

EDIT:

Tried using a class method instead of a scope:

```
def self.price_for_diamond(diamond)
  Price.where("colour = ? AND clarity = ? AND weight_min < ? AND weight_max > ?",
                  diamond.color_code, diamond.clarity_code, diamond.carat_weight, 
                  diamond.carat_weight).first
end
```

Still no luck though.

Comment: Scopes should always return a chainable ActiveRecord::Relation - what you are trying to do may work, but is not a good idea. It should simply be defined as a class method.

Comment: Hi, i tried using a class method, added above, still ge the error.

Comment: so `price_for_diamond` is now a class method on the Price object and it returns a Price object? And you still can't assign it to `d.price`?